# Rails validate uniqueness on level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I have ancestry tree in my app.

I want to implement uniqueness for records only on the same level.

let me explain

Records:

```
 #<Folder id: 1, title: "folder1", ... ancestry: nil>,
 #<Folder id: 2, title: "folder2", ... ancestry: "1">,
 #<Folder id: 3, title: "folder3", ... ancestry: "1/2">
```

if i want to to create `folder (:title => 'folder2', :ancestry => '1')` it should raise an error `title is olready taken`,

but if i create  `folder (:title => 'folder2', :ancestry => nil or "1/2")` it should create new record.

probably someone have this problem, and can give advice or answer

(in ancestry method @elem.siblings returns all records on @elem level)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The uniqueness validator can accept a `scope` parameter:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title, :scope => :ancestry
```

It will now validate that title us unique amongst records with the same ancestry value.